# How to format matrix values in powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a powerbi matrix similar to below where some of the cells are negatives. I would like to see the negative numbers in `()`. How do I get around with this ? Many thanks in advance.

[image: this]

Comment: https://bioffthegrid.com/show-negative-numbers-in-brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the column and in the column tools, type a custom format e.g.

[image]

[image]

```
$,#;($,#)
```